# merge two videos with AVMutableComposition, but one of them didnt play well

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

here i have two videos, both of them are mp4, and i want to merge them in one piece to play one by one with AVPlayerItem. but just one of them play well, the other one just show black screen while the progress is still rolling. the annoying thing is , they both get played well independently. have anyone encounter this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this link will help you.

https://iosdevelopercloud.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/merge-multiple-videos-in-objective-c/

Comment: thx for answering, but i need a solution instead of a introduction now